# Stored procedure exercise AP database SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, error-messaging

I created this stored procedure, but I am getting so many errors that I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. If someone could help that would be awesome.

**Directions**

Write a stored procedure using transactional processing that inserts a new row into the `Vendor` table and then adds at least one new `Invoice` and `InvoiceLineItems` for that new `Vendor`. This program must include the ability to handle a failed transaction in which case it should issue an error message and a rollback.

My code:

```
USE AP

CREATE PROCEDURE Test02_sp 
AS
    @VendorName VARCHAR(50),
    @VendorCity VARCHAR(50),
    @VendorState CHAR(2),
    @VendorZipCode VARCHAR(20),
    @ShipName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ShipRegion VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ShipPostalCode VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ShipCountry VARCHAR(MAX),
    @CustomerID INT,
    @CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Address VARCHAR(MAX),
    @City VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Region VARCHAR(MAX),
    @PostalCode VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Country VARCHAR(MAX),
    @DefaultTermsID INT = NULL,
    @DefaultAccountNo INT = NULL,
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Vendor
        ADD DefaultTermsID INT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT Vendor_DefaultTermsID DEFAULT 3

    ALTER TABLE Vendor 
        ADD COLUMN VendorID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    GO

    ALTER TABLE Vendor 
        ADD DF_Vendors_AccountNo INT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT Vendor_DF_Vendors_AccountNo DEFAULT 570
    GO

    ALTER TABLE Vendor 
        ADD DefaultTermsID INT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT Vendor_DefaultTermsID DEFAULT 3
    GO

    INSERT INTO Vendor
    VALUES (@VendorName, @VendorCity, @VendorState, @VendorZipCode, @DefaultTermsID, @DefaultAccountNo)
    GO

    INSERT INTO Invoices 
    VALUES (@ShipName, @ShipAddress, @ShipCity, @ShipRegion, @ShipPostalCode, @ShipCountry, 
            @CustomerID, @CompanyName, @Address, @City, @Region, @PostalCode, @Country)
    GO
END
```

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server syntax on a question tagged MySQL?

Comment: sorry I accidently tagged it

Comment: Remove `ALTER TABLE` code blocks and `GO` keywords from the body (that is between `BEGIN` and `END` tags) of your SP. You should have something like `BEGIN INSERT INTO Vendor ..... INSERT INTO Invoices ..... END`

Comment: The code you posted - even if it worked - does not match your instructions. There is no indication that your procedure should modify the structure or definition of the table. If that is a requirement, then consider what happens when the procedure is run more than once. Start over. You define or refine the structure of your tables separately from writing code to manipulate the content of those tables - generally speaking. And no - your parameters should not be defined as varchar(max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply Transaction to your query.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
BEGIN TRY

    ALTER TABLE Vendor
    ADD DefaultTermsID int NULL CONSTRAINT Vendor_DefaultTermsID DEFAULT 3

    ALTER TABLE Vendor ADD COLUMN VendorID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

    ALTER TABLE Vendor ADD DF_Vendors_AccountNo int NULL CONSTRAINT
    Vendor_DF_Vendors_AccountNo DEFAULT 570

    ALTER TABLE Vendor ADD DefaultTermsID int NULL CONSTRAINT Vendor_DefaultTermsID DEFAULT 3

    INSERT INTO Vendor
    VALUES (@VendorName,@VendorCity,@VendorState,@VendorZipCode,@DefaultTermsID,@DefaultAccountNo)

    INSERT INTO Invoices 
    VALUES (@ShipName,@ShipAddress,@ShipCity,@ShipRegion,@ShipPostalCode,@ShipCountry,@CustomerID,@CompanyName,@Address,@City,@Region,@PostalCode,@Country)


    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'In Catch. Error occured', 4,  @@TRANCOUNT

     IF (XACT_STATE()) = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            N'There is no transaction'

    END;


     IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +
            'Rolling back transaction.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    -- Test whether the transaction is committable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            N'The transaction is committable.' +
            'Committing transaction.'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
    END;


END CATCH
```